# Is this approach to fix a typing error between typescript and Contentful's content delivery API safe?

Tags: typescript, contentful, astrojs, contentful-api

I'm using Astro and Contentful to make a blog. I have a content type called `author` which has 3 fields.

| Name | Field Type |
| --- | --- |
| Full Name | Short text |
| Headshot | Media |
| Bio | Rich Text |

I'm working on creating a component that will list out all the authors. My code looks as follows:

```
---
import { contentfulClient } from "../lib/contentful";
import { documentToHtmlString } from "@contentful/rich-text-html-renderer";
import type { Asset, EntryFieldTypes } from "contentful";


interface Author {
    contentTypeId: "author",
    fields: {
        fullName: EntryFieldTypes.Text,
        headshot: EntryFieldTypes.AssetLink,
        bio: EntryFieldTypes.RichText
    }
}

const authors = await contentfulClient.getEntries<Author>({
    content_type: "author"
})

---
<h1>Authors</h1>
{
    authors.items.map((author) => (
        <p>{author.fields.fullName}</p>
        <img src={`https:${(author.fields.headshot as any).fields.file.url}`} alt="" srcset="">
    ))
}
```

This works but I had to cast `author.fields.headshot` as `any` because typescript was complaining that `fields` wasn't a property of headshot. And my intellisense could only find `sys` as a property of `headshot`.

So this:

```
<img src={`https:${author.fields.headshot.fields.file.url}`} class="w-full max-w-48" alt="" srcset="">
```

Does work locally. But when I go to deploy to Netlify the build fails since typescript won't compile. My solution works but it feels dangerous. I thought maybe I was using the wrong `EntryFieldTypes` property in my `Author` interface but `AssetLink` seems to be the most appropriate.

Comment: Is that meant to be JSX? You have multiple elements with no parent in the `map` callback, no closing `/` on the `img`, and `srcset` rather than `srcSet` on the `img`. I was trying to recreate the error in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) but those issues make me wonder if I'm missing some context...?

Comment: Just doing an `any` assertion isn't generally safe, no; it's basically opting out of type checking entirely. I don't use contentful but I wanted to help if I could: Looking at the contentful source linked from the docs, [`AssetLink`](https://github.com/contentful/contentful.js/blob/eb4edcbd0ba0f687f9bf4fe6bfa4e051e294cdeb/lib/types/entry.ts#L45) has no properties other than `type`, which makes it not very useful. Pardon my ignorance, but would `EntryLink` or `ResourceLink` make sense? Those support an entry skeleton type param... Anyway, I doubt I can be more useful than that. Good hunting!

Comment: Astro has it's own file extension but in the docs it's described as JSX like expressions. I am using the astro extension which should catch any kind of syntax error so I don't believe that's the problem. And yeah I really wasn't happy with the any assertion so even though it works and deploys I figured I'd ask. EntryLink and ResourceLink don't seem to work either but they require a type parameter and maybe I'm just not supplying that correctly. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Running into the same issue, did you ever manage to figure it out?

Comment: I'm sorry but I did not.

Answer (score 1):

The Contentful TypeScript definitions are really quite something. Smells heavily like they had to tack them on a dynamic js lib after the fact.

I had a look at [their tutorial](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/javascript/tutorials/typescript-in-javascript-client-library/) which mentions `EntryFieldTypes.Asset`, which doesn't exist. But the closest I got is:

```
import { type Asset, type EntryFieldTypes } from 'contentful'

const headshot: Asset;

(author.fields.headshot as Asset).fields.file?.url
```

Note the `as Asset` is still needed, because the [Entry type](https://github.com/contentful/contentful.js/blob/eb4edcbd0ba0f687f9bf4fe6bfa4e051e294cdeb/lib/types/entry.ts#L265) for some reason sets the type of the field `headshot` to `never`. (The `author` variable is not of type `Author` but of type `Entry<Author, undefined, string>`.)

Finally, you could try [generating the types automatically](https://github.com/contentful/contentful.js/blob/master/TYPESCRIPT.md#generating-type-definitions-for-content-types).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your headshot field should be of type `Asset` not `AssetLink` which is a link within a rich text structure.

```
headshot: Asset,
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something because EntryFieldTypes has no exported member called Asset. Just AssetLink.

Comment: That's weird, this is from the docs: image: Contentful.EntryFieldTypes.Asset, https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/javascript/tutorials/typescript-in-javascript-client-library/

the thing is, you want an Asset, not an AssetLink, because the asset link is just a representation of a link to an asset, you have an actual asset.

Comment: Yeah very weird. I'll continue digging into this. Thanks for your direction. This might be the path forward.

Answer (score 0):

When you define `headshot` as an `EntryFieldTypes.AssetLink`, TypeScript expects a specific structure for that field, which does not include the nested `fields` property directly.

To resolve this, you need to properly type the structure of the AssetLink and its nested properties. The `AssetLink` should have a `sys` property and potentially other properties depending on how Contentful structures it.

Here's how you can adjust your types:

```js
interface Author {
    contentTypeId: "author",
    fields: {
        fullName: EntryFieldTypes.Text,
        headshot: Asset,
        bio: EntryFieldTypes.RichText
    }
}

// Define the structure of an Asset based on Contentful's data model
interface Asset {
  sys: { id: string };
  fields: { 
    file: { 
      url: string;
      details?: any; // Include any additional expected properties here
      fileName?: string;
      contentType?: string;
    }; 
  };
}
```

By defining an `Asset` interface that matches what Contentful returns, you help TypeScript understand the shape of your data. This way, when you access `author.fields.headshot.fields.file.url`, TypeScript knows what to expect.

THe component code should also be adjusted:

```
<h1>Authors</h1>
{
    authors.items.map((author) => (
        <>
            <p>{author.fields.fullName}</p>
            {/* Make sure to check if headshot and file are defined before accessing url */}
            <img src={author.fields.headshot && author.fields.headshot.fields.file.url ? `https:${author.fields.headshot.fields.file.url}` : ''} alt="" class="w-full max-w-48" />
        </>
    ))
}
```

Each element is wrapped in a fragment (`<>...</>`) because `.map()` must return a single element. Also, I added checks before accessing nested properties like `.file.url`. This will prevent runtime errors if some authors don't have a headshot assigned.

Let me know if this deploys or not...

Comment: I tried this exactly as you suggested and this is the typescript error I'm getting as a result. 

Property 'fields' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)

This is over the fields property.